# Particles and Freestyle

Tags: particles, freestyle

I have a cube with "hair/path" particles and an other with "hair/object" particles. 
The first on render in freestyle, the second do not. 
If I apply particles then yes, render in freestyle, but I loose the scope of having flexibility and animation I have with particles.

Is there a way to render in freestyle a hair/object ?

thank you for any answer.

[image: result]
[image: hair/path]

[image: hair / object]

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm not understanding the problem. I tried with a cube and a plane and it looks fine https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNBrw.png. Maybe your object is too thin to be detected? Are you using any particular settings in your setup?

Comment: I did try the same setup you show in the link, even activating any single option in freestyle line set (see picture https://imgur.com/a/hUUpKMi), but instead of getting the same result you get, I have always the same problem: hair/path renders, hair/object do not!

Comment: You can try to re-build a test scene from scratch with fewer possible options and see if the problem persist or upload your file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so we can inspect what's going on.

Comment: thank you! I did try again from scratch, as suggested from you, and it works! I compared the two files for a long time, in freestyle settings and particles settings, but they seem identical to me. Here are the links, the file witch does not work. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4825" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4825/) and the file working : [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4826" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4826/)